# Java PDF Library that works on GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, pdf

Since GAE has severe restrictions like - "A Java application cannot use any classes used to write to the filesystem"...

Is there a good Java PDF library that can write the PDF to memory for streaming to the cloud?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/a06dd822a6cee160/162ad3799bf3be56?lnk=raot) on google groups (requires authentication), [PDFjet](http://pdfjet.com/os/download.html) can be used on GAE (it has been slightly modified to replace files by streams at a few places). As they say in the thread:

> It's a quite low-level library but should be ok for simple tasks.

As of now, both iText and JasperReports are listed as **incompatible** on the ["Will it play in App Engine"](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/web/will-it-play-in-app-engine) page due to the dependence on several classes that are not in the [JRE class whitelist](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html).

---

**Update (2010/09/26):** As mentioned by [Guido](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12388/guido) in a comment (and I thank him for that), *some people claim they have an [iText patch to make it compatible with GAE](http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/12/17/how-to-run-itext-on-google-app-engine/)*. Worth the try if you want to play with iText.

Comment: Cool. That is exactly the lead I needed.

Comment: Some people claim they have an iText patch to make it compatible with GAE : http://blog.rubypdf.com/2009/12/17/how-to-run-itext-on-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 7):

You can use iText without limitations now. There is no need for a patch since version 5.2.0 anymore.

Have a look at the following post for an example: [Generate PDF using GAE and iText](http://floonit.blogspot.de/2012/07/generate-pdf-using-google-app-engine.html)

Comment: thanks for the update :) I look forward to remerging my standalone pdf generator service back into the gae code and saving the PDFs into the blobstore